# pycrypto and python 2.4.3 issue

Tags: python, pycrypto

I am working on a project and the cPanel which is provided to me by employer is having `python 2.4.3` (too old version). The problem is i need to use `pycrypto`. So i am importing `SHA256`. The problem is here SHA256.py:

```
try:
    import hashlib
    hashFactory = hashlib.sha256

except ImportError:
    from Crypto.Hash import _SHA256
    hashFactory = _SHA256
```

`hashlib` is not available in python 2.4.3 so it went to import `_SHA256` but there is no _SHA256 in `Cryto.Hash` folder. Is this is bug of pycrypto? or i can not use this module for python 2.4.3?? Any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [standalone hashlib library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashlib/20060408a).

Comment: I downloaded the library and got this error `from hashlib import sha256
ImportError: cannot import name sha256`

Comment: That's because it's not a module in a package, ``hashlib`` is the module. ``import hashlib`` then ``hashlib.sha256()`` is what you want. See http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html for more.

Comment: Do i need to install this module first? using python setup.py install? I am directly using this library without installing it and after doing `import hashlib` then `hashlib.sha256()` i am now getting this error: `hashlib.py, line 63, in __get_builtin_constructor, import _md5 ImportError: No module named _md5`

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few algorithms in PyCrypto are actually written in C, rather than in pure python. SHA256 is amongst them. In order to use it, you must either install a complete pycrypto binary package or follow the instructions in the PyCrypto's README file. In the latter case, you will need to install the development environment first.

Both options are platform and OS specific, but once done, it will be simply a matter of calling:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
hash = SHA256.new()
hash.update('message')
```

There is no need to try to import it from `hashlib` first.